# SQL SELECT incremental batch number every X rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to write a SQL SELECT query that has a batch number column that increments every 5 rows, I've tried using a hacky integer division on a dynamic row number, but can't get around the first batch number increment always being 4 rows instead of 5 (see image).

RowNumber 1-5 should be 1, 6-10 should be 2 etc..

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```
select * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select 0)) AS RowNumber,
1 + convert(int, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select 0)) / 5)) as BatchNumber,
* from WorkQueue
```

[image]

Comment: Subtract 1 from your second row_number use.
    1 + convert(int, ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select 0)) -1 )/ 5)) as BatchNumber.

ROW_NUMBER starts counting at 1 rather than zero which is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select 0)) AS RowNumber,
(case when convert(int, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select 0)) % 5))=0 then 0 else 1 end) + convert(int, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select 0)) / 5)) as BatchNumber,
* from WorkQueue
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumber,
        CEILING(CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS DECIMAL(10,2))/5) AS BatchNo, *
FROM    WorkQueue
```