# SQL - Generate bi-weekly end date on custom start date

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, date, datetime

I want to get a custom Fort Night period based on a given start date.
I have a table that looks like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tbl1
SET DATEFIRST 1
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME

SET @StartDateTime = '2016-09-03'
SET @EndDateTime = '2017-01-28';

WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateData ASC) As ROWNum,DateData AS Date1
into  #tbl1
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
GO

SELECT top 10 * FROM #tbl1

         Date1
        2016-09-09 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-10 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-11 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-12 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-13 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-14 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-15 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-16 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-17 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-18 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-19 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-20 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-21 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
```

I want to say the the first date of my bi-weekly period is 2016-09-09 and it ends 2016-09-22. How do I get bi-weekly end date for each of those dates.

So I want it to look like

```
         Date1                           FortNightEndDate
        2016-09-09 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-10 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-11 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-12 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-13 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-14 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-15 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-16 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-17 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-18 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-19 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-20 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-21 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
        2016-09-22 00:00:00.000       2016-09-22 00:00:00.000
```

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

ANSWER:
I was able to solve it using the following code. Essentially I just created 3 tables:
StartDates
EndDates
InbetweenDates

The Start/EndDates tables had just the start and End of my 2 week period and an ID (Row Number)
The InbetweenDates table had all the dates between the 2 dates and also had a ID column but instead of going up 1 every row, it went up 1 every 14 rows.
Then I just joined the 3 tables. Essentially, the Start/EndDates tables were lookup tables.
I got the RowNumber on every 14 days code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526622/sql-select-incremental-batch-number-every-x-rows).

```
-- BEtween Dates
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BetweenDates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #BetweenDates
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME

SET @StartDateTime = '2016-09-09'
SET @EndDateTime = '2017-04-30';

WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
)
SELECT 
    DateData
into  #BetweenDates
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
GO



select 
    (case when convert(int, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select 0)) % 14))=0 then 0 else 1 end) 
    + convert(int, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select 0)) / 14)) as ID
    ,DateData
INTO #BetweenDates_ID
from #BetweenDates


-- Start Dates

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#StartDates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #StartDates
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME

SET @StartDateTime = '2016-09-09'
SET @EndDateTime = '2017-04-30';

WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,14,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateData ASC) As ID,DateData
into  #StartDates
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
GO

-- End Dates

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EndDates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #EndDates
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME

SET @StartDateTime = '2016-09-22'
SET @EndDateTime = '2017-04-30';

WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,14,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateData ASC) As ID,DateData
into  #EndDates
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
GO


--SELECT * FROM #StartDates
--SELECT * FROM #EndDates
--SELECT * FROM #BetweenDates_ID

SELECT 
    st.DateData AS StartDate
    ,ed.DateData AS EndDate
    ,bd.DateData AS BetweenDate
FROM 
    #StartDates st
    JOIN
    #EndDates ed
    ON st.ID = ed.ID
    LEFT JOIN
    #BetweenDates_ID bd
    ON st.ID = bd.ID
```

Comment: What is bi-weekly end date? How do you compute it?

Comment: Essentially I need fortnight end date from Wed to Thur (2 weeks). In the example, all dates from 2016-09-09 to 2016-09-22 belong to fortnight end date 2016-09-22

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Date1,
       DATEADD(DD, -1, DATEADD(WW,2,Date1)) AS FortNightEndDate
FROM #tbl1
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It adds 2 weeks to each date. I need to get fort night end date. Same as you would get a week end date or month end date. For example it would know that 2016-09-05 to 2016-09-011 (y/m/d) all belong to week ending 2016-09-11 (week starts Mon). I need the same thing but for 2 weeks starting on a Thur